# First countable space and $\tau \subset \tau^*$

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau$ and $\tau^*$ be topologies on X with $\tau$ coarser than $\tau^*$ i.e  $ \tau \subset \tau^*$.
(i) Show that if (X,$\tau^*$) first countable, then (X,$\tau$) is also first countable

I have tried to solve this exercise but I think you can not have that relationship between (X,$\tau^*$) and (X,$\tau$). I may have a suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were this true, then *every* topology would be first-countable. This is because for every set $X$, the *discrete topology* $\tau_D$ on $X$ is clearly first countable (for each $x \in X$ the family $\{ \{ x \} \}$ is a neighborhood base at $x$). Also, for any other topology $\tau$ on $X$ we have $\tau \subseteq \tau_D$, and so $\tau$ would have to be first-countable (assuming the statement you want to prove is true).

But, of course, there are many topologies which are not first-countable. An example is the usual (order) topology on the closed ordinal space $[0,\omega_1]$, where there is no countable neighborhood base at $\omega_1$. (More examples can be found on [π-Base](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=%7EFirst%20Countable).)